# How to query an array of _id in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have collection `Collection1` and I need to fetch an array like: `[id1, id2, id3, ...]` (array which consist of _id`s for every element in this collection). Is there any way to do this query with MongoDB tools ? Thank you!

Comment: Just use [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) -> `db.Collection1.distinct("_id")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use `cursor.toArray()` function on result of `find` having a projection document projecting only `_id` i.e `ObjectId()` value

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.users.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("570e1d465a44f125ef156791"),
        "name" : "Ritesh Talreja",
        "age" : 22,
        "gender" : "M"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("570e1e1d5a44f125ef156792"),
        "name" : "Saloni",
        "age" : 21,
        "gender" : "F"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("570e1e485a44f125ef156793"),
        "name" : "abcd",
        "age" : 22,
        "gender" : "M"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("570e28d45a44f125ef156794"),
        "name" : "Saloni",
        "age" : 21,
        "gender" : "F"
}
{ "_id" : 123 }
MongoDB Enterprise > db.users.find({}, {_id:1}).toArray()
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("570e1d465a44f125ef156791")
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("570e1e1d5a44f125ef156792")
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("570e1e485a44f125ef156793")
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("570e28d45a44f125ef156794")
        },
        {
                "_id" : 123
        }
]
MongoDB Enterprise >
```

As an addition you can also use:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.users.distinct("_id")
[
        123,
        ObjectId("570e1d465a44f125ef156791"),
        ObjectId("570e1e1d5a44f125ef156792"),
        ObjectId("570e1e485a44f125ef156793"),
        ObjectId("570e28d45a44f125ef156794")
]
MongoDB Enterprise >
```